# How do I tell what plugins are used on my multisite install?

Tags: plugins, multisite

I have a bunch of plugins I have installed but never use, others I am not sure if they are used or not. Is there a way to tell what plugins are not active on any site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This plugin](http://trepmal.com/plugins/active-plugins-on-multisite/) does what you want. From the site: "Generates a list of plugins that are currently in use, excluding Network-Activated" - hope that helps!